# Teradata- DDL with column holding milliseconds only

Tags: teradata, milliseconds

Is there a way i can create a column in a table which will only hold milliseconds value. I have a requirement where i have to store only LLLCCC(milliseconds) value in a column.

Comment: can't you use integer(6) for that??

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store a valid interval which you can manipulate as an interval (aggregate, perform interval arithmetic against, etc.) you can use the data type `INTERVAL SECOND(1,6)` in your table definition. If all values must be less than 1 second you can use a column level constraint to enforce the acceptable range of values.

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE MyTable, NO FALLBACK
(ColA SMALLINT NOT NULL,
 MyInterval INTERVAL SECOND(1,6) NOT NULL)
PRIMARY INDEX (ColA) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (1, INTERVAL '0.244569' SECOND);

SELECT *
  FROM MyTable;
```

**EDIT:**

You can certainly store these values outside of their native format using CHAR(6), DECIMAL(6),  or INTEGER. However, your ability to manipulate the values outside their native format becomes complicated.

Comment: Thanks Rob, that did work :-) but can i only store 244569 in the column...with the time format??

@user2407394 : i am sorry i know we can store that as integer. But i don't know as of now for what this column is gonna be used for so trying to consider all scenarios and pros and cons for that